# How do I increment a Twitter Bootstrap progress bar in HAML?

Tags: css, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, sinatra, haml

I am just starting to learn building small web apps using Sinatra, HAML and Twitter Bootstrap.

In my application, an action takes place every 500 seconds. I would like to place a progress bar on my page which indicates the time remaining until the next action takes places. Right now the bar should just update if the page is reloaded.

I am calculating the progress of the bar like this:

```
-percentage = (Time.now.to_i.modulo(500))/5
```

Right now, in my prototype HAML page layout, I have a progress bar like this:

```
%div.progress.progress-striped.active
  %div.bar{:style => "width: 40%;"}
```

I am struggling to figure out the correct syntax to set the `width` attribute of the progress bar to the previously calculated progress percentage.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out I can simply place the percentage in the attribute like this:

```
%div.progress.progress-striped.active
  %div.bar{:style => "width: #{percentage}%;"}
```

I was confused because I was thinking I need to "enable" Ruby code in this like, similar to using the trailing `-` or `=` sign if I want to evaluate Ruby code in HAML.